# How to open second window on button click in electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I have a button in my index.html that I would like to open a second window when clicked.

I have added the following to my index.js:

```
const button = document.getElementById('newtask');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  newtaskwindow();
});

function newtaskwindow() {
  const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 400,
    width: 600
  });

  win.loadURL('createtasks.html');
}
```

On npm start, I'm getting the following error: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a second js file and input:

```
const button = document.getElementById('newtask');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  newtaskwindow();
});

function newtaskwindow() {
  const remote = require('electron').remote;
  const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  });

  win.loadURL('createtasks.html');
}
```

Comment: It does not work , also the new approach is to use `loadFile`